# How do I get my 1024 wide web page to display on my Nexus 7 in Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, viewport

I have a 1024 x 768 web page which works fine everywhere but Nexus 7 Chrome (newest as of 5 March 2013)

I have tried lots of viewport meta tags and other techniques, but my page is always cropped and cannot fit into the 1280 pixels of this device. Works fine on iPads and iPhones.

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't set your viewport up correctly.  I have tested it here http://jsbin.com/ubumef/latest with the following code and the viewport it scaled to the correct width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Viewport Width: 1024px</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024px" />
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0px;">
    <div style="width: 1024px; background-color:red;">This is 1024px</div>
    <div style="width: 512px; margin-top: 5px; background-color:blue;">This is 512px</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope. Nexus 7 Chrome messes that up badly. Changing orientation of the tablet and/or tapping on the screen gives several different widths, some of which may be cropped - you can't tell if the right end is cropped in any of those.

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot paulkinlan at google dot com - I tested this on nexus 7 - tapping on the screen is zoom mode, you can disable this too.